# How to maintain an icon for a file, when I move that file from a device to another

Tags: files, icons

I wonder if it is possible to maintain an icon associated with a file, when I copy that file from my HDD to an external device (e.g., USB, external HDD, etc.).

In particular, when I want to "rank" a file I follow the procedure:

Right click on that file → properties → left click on the image in the upper-left side of the window → then I select an icon.

However, when I copy that file from my HDD to my USB device, the icon disappears, and I loose my evaluation of that file.

Do you know if it is possible to maintain an associated icon to a file?
More generally, is there any package or simple method to permanently associate an icon to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Meta data are not stored with the folder. So what I suggest is to use:

https://github.com/despens/metasave

A script that store meta data before moving/copying folder, then run the generated shell script to restore them.